# Steam controller in blender game engine

Tags: game-engine

I recently got a steam controller and I am wondering if there's a way to use the input from the controller to control my blender game?

Comment: If your controller can connect to your computer (whether that be via cord, bluetooth or wifi), then yes you can. There is a logic brick known as the joystick sensor which you can use to define which buttons perform what actions.